# Unable to install ngx-doc-viewer in angular 9

Tags: angular, npm, angular9, ngx-doc-viewer

I am trying to install ngx-doc-viewer in angular 9 project. But it throws some error, here I have attached the error. Anyone faced this issues?

**or**

**Suggest me any other document viewer using angular 9**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: app@0.0.147
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@9.0.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~9.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^11.2.0" from ngx-doc-viewer@2.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer
npm ERR!   ngx-doc-viewer@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a **dependency conflict** (**incorrect** and **potentially** broken dependency).

Try to to run the `npm install` command with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps.`

**OR:**

Workaround is to use the `--force` flag when running `ng update` [package] to override the dependency issues.

```
ng update ngx-doc-viewer --next --force
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, But it is working now once downgrade my nodejs version from version-15.0.1 to version-12.11.1